# spawn Enemies in 3 specific places on the screen Swift SpriteKit IOS

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, sprite-kit

i'm building a game in swift, with SpriteKit and at the moment my enemies spawn randomly across the screen, and i want my enemies to spawn only in 3 places, for example top left, top center, and top right. Also the spawning to be random between this 3 places. I tryed some code but i'm beginner, I need some help from you guys, THANKS

```
   //Generate the random Number

func random() -> CGFloat {
    return CGFloat(Float(arc4random()) / 0xFFFFFFFF)
}
func random(min min: CGFloat, max: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
    return random() * (max - min) + min
}
```

Here is the code for the spawing Enemies

```
 func spawnEnemy() {



     let randomXStart = random(min: CGRectGetMinX(gameArea), max:  CGRectGetMaxX(gameArea))
     let startPoint = CGPoint(x: randomXStart, y: self.size.height * 1.2)
```

Comment: scene's anchorPoint when loading from sks file is 0.5, 0.5. Means the sprite will be added to the center of the screen by default. Top left corner is -sceneWidth/2, -sceneHeight/2. Top right corner is sceneWidth/2, sceneHeight/2. Point between these two points is 0,sceneHeight/2. To randomize sprite's x position, just generate random value betwwen -sceneWidth/2 and sceneWidth/2.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
func spawnEnemy() {
     let randomXStart = random(min: 0, max:  2)
     let startPoint = CGPoint(x: randomXStart * self.size.width/2, y: self.size.height * 1.2)
     .
     .
     .
 }
```

This generates a random number of other 0, 1 or 2. The x position of your sprite is then set to half the screen width * this random number which will generate x positions of 0 (top-left corner), self.size.width/2 (i.e. half-way across the screen) or self.size.width (i.e. the top right corner).

You might need to slightly adjust these depending upon the `anchorPoint` of your sprite, so you could also do the following:

```
func spawnEnemy() {
     let randomXStart = random(min: 0, max:  2)

     switch floor(randomXStart) {
     case 0 :          
          let startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: self.size.height * 1.2) + (adjustment factor for top-left corner)
     case 1 :          
          let startPoint = CGPoint(x: self.size.width/2, y: self.size.height * 1.2) + (adjustment factor for top-middle)
     case 2 :          
          let startPoint = CGPoint(x: self.size.width, y: self.size.height * 1.2) + (adjustment factor for top-right corner)
     default : break
     }
     .
     .
     .
 }
```

Comment: thanks, but I have one more question,

i used your func spawnEnemy() 
but now when i try to put the enemy.position = randomXtart it doesnt work: it says cannot asign values of time() to type CGpoint, so my enemy position can't acces the case 0,1,2

and also cant make startPoint = CGPoint(x: spawnEnemy, y:spawnEnemy)

What i can do?

Comment: @DanielArdeleanu Can you post this new code where you have enemy.position = randomXstart and are getting a message about time().

Comment: It worked with first function that you provided: 
`func spawnEnemy() { let randomXStart = random(min: 0, max: 2) let startPoint = CGPoint(x: randomXStart * self.size.width/2, y: self.size.height * 1.2)

  let startPoint = CGPoint(x: randomXStart * self.size.width/2, y: self.size.height * 0.8)`

 For the second one with switch randomXtart, it doesnt work cuse i dont know how to access it.  So i have a position : `enemy.position = startPoint that works with first function, at second function(the one with switch) i can't put enemy.position = startPoint, it cannot acces the cases

Comment: thanks for the answer, it really helped me to do the thing that i wanted, now i've learned how to use the random function better. And in future i'm sure i will learn also how to access switch statements.

Comment: @DanielArdeleanu There was an error in the second example (a close bracket in the parms). also, your random() functions return CGFloats, so you'll need to convert the result to an Int for the Switch to work See my edit.